# Can someone help deconstruct the sentence "Hicieron usted su tarea para hoy?"

Tags: traducción, gramática, pretérito

A possible translation of the sentence "`Hicieron usted su tarea para hoy?`" could be:

> *Did you do your homework (for) today?*

That said, `hicieron` is the preterit of `hacer` for third person plural, so why is the sentence not something such as:

> Hicieron ustedes sus tarea para hoy?

Thanks!

Comment: >why is the sentence not something such as 'Hicieron' ?
because it's wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, *`¿hicieron usted su tarea para hoy?`* **is** incorrect.

As you say, for the third person plural the correct way to say it is:

> ¿Hicieron ustedes su tarea para hoy?

Answer (score 2):

In Spanish you may omit the subject (in this case, *ustedes*) when the verb hints at it (*[sujeto tácito](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sujeto_t%C3%A1cito)*), so the commonly used form is the following:

> ¿Hicieron su tarea de hoy?

Why not `¿Hicieron su tarea para hoy?`?.  Let me explain the difference with another example:

> ¿Construyeron el muro **para** María?

means to ask if the wall built was intended *for* María or not, while

> ¿Construyeron el muro **de** María?

means to ask if María's wall was indeed built.

With this in mind, you can now see that the alternative in gray is asking whether [they] did their homework *intending it for* today, rather than if [they] did today's homework or not.

In reality, both questions will be perfectly understood, it's just that one is not entirely correct.

**Regarding your question** about why `su tarea` and not `sus tarea`:

The first part (`hicieron [ustedes]`) is plural, but the direct object `su tarea` is singular because `tarea` is commonly used as a collective word (just as you don't say `homeworks`).

Let me pose a different example for this:

> - ¿Tienes tu llave?     // Do you *[one person]* have your key?
> - ¿Tienes tus llaves?  // Do you *[one person]* have your keys?

^ Here it is clear that the individual subject is asked first for a single key and then for multiple keys.

> - ¿Tienen su llave?   // Do you *[people]* have your key?

^ Even with plural subject, it is clear that the question asks for everyone to have *exactly one key* (*i.e.*, singular direct object).

> - ¿Tienen sus llaves?   // Do you *[people]* have your keys?

Please note that this last question is now (slightly) ambiguous in both languages.  It could mean to ask for one single key per person (they collectively have keys), or it could mean that every individual might have multiple keys.

While this is not very surprising, analyzing this could help you understand the translation to Spanish.

As a last note, a teacher that left multiple assignments, who wants to clearly emphasize that fact *could* say:

> ¿Hicieron sus tareas?

Hope this helps :)